# Which of these statements about biholomorphic functions $f \colon D(0, 1) → D(0, 1)$ is true?

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f \colon D(0, 1) → D(0, 1)$ is a biholomorphic function.
>
> **a)** $f$ must be constant
>
> **b)** $f$ must have a fixed point
>
> **c)** $f$ must be a rotation
>
> **d)** $f$ must fix the origin.

Any such map looks like $e^{i\alpha}{(z-a)\over (1-\bar{a}z)}$, $a\in D$, $\alpha\in [0,2\pi]$, so only **c** is correct option?

Comment: In the future, please make the titles of your posts actual *questions*, so that people can understand what each post is about when searching the site or reading the front page.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: okay thank you I must follow

Comment: How come you know what all the biholomorpihc functions look like, but still can't choose a correct option? According to your own formula, it is a rotation iff $a = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to keep in mind the classification of biholomorphic self-maps of $\mathbb D$ (also known as orientation-preserving isometries of the hyperbolic plane in the disk model) into

- [hyperbolic](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~crobles/hyperbolic/hypr/isom/pncr/hypr/), which look like translation, and have no fixed points in $\mathbb D$

[image: hyperbolic]

- [parabolic](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~crobles/hyperbolic/hypr/isom/pncr/para/), which look like rotation about a boundary point (which is not a point in $\mathbb D$). They have no fixed points either:

[image: parabolic]

- [elliptic](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~crobles/hyperbolic/hypr/isom/pncr/elli/), which look like rotation about a point in $\mathbb D$ (which is a fixed point).

[image: elliptic]

(The author of the materials linked above is Colleen Robles, as far as I can tell.)

a) clearly false: a bi-(anything) function cannot be constant.

b) c), d) are disproved by an example of  hyperbolic or parabolic isometry